# What is the result of using negative inf here

Tags: python

```
def covidLQ(array, n):
    lastSpot = float('-inf')
    i = 0

    while i < n:
        if array[i] == 1:
            if (i - lastSpot) < 6:
                return 'NO'
            else:
                lastSpot = i
        i += 1
    return 'YES'

for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    array = list(map(int, input('').split()))
    print(covidLQ(array, n))
```

The situation right now is if the distance b\w `A = array[i]` and next or previous point B is 6 or above then return yes, else return no. Here I don't understand if what can come out if i - a negative infinite number, how to know if it is 6?

Also, what is `_` in `for _in range(int(input)))`? Is it just a meaningless symbol or something else?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some context. What problem are you trying to solve? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: When posting here, please observe the usual case rules for English, use a spell-checker, and avoid made-up words like "plz". Technical writing is recommended. A particular lack of care often results in downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interactive python interpreter is a great tool for understanding this code:

```
>>> float("-inf")
-inf
>>> 0 - float("-inf")
inf
>>> 10000 - float("-inf")
inf
```

Any time you subtract `-inf` (aka, negative infinity) from a finite number, the result is `inf` (aka, positive infinity). No matter what value `i` has, the first time `array[i] == 1` is `True` then `(i - lastSpot) < 6` is `False` and `lastSpot` is set to the value of `i`.

Comment: so  ` ( i - lastSpot) ` is always false ??

Comment: No,  the value of `lastSpot` changes each time `(i - lastSpot) < 6` is `False` by the line `lastSpot = i`. After the first time `array[i]` is `1`, it will depend on the next value of `i` where `array[i]` has a value of `1`.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the loop would exit and return `NO` the first time `array[i]` had a value of `1`.

Comment: also , could you tell me what is the meaning of _ in  ```for _ in range(int(input)) ```   , plz